# SwiftUI App doesn't launch on macOS after using @ObservedObject in Xcode 11 Beta 7

Tags: macos, binding, swiftui, xcode11, macos-catalina

If I create a plain macOS App using the default template with SwiftUI (or even if I create an iOS App and enable macOS compatibility), the App starts fine if the main view has @EnvironmentObject as the datasource, but if the datasource is @ObservedObject, the App compiles but doesn't run, and crashed on the ScenDelegate.

Take this simple model of `Person` as an example:

```
class Person: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""    
}
```

If I create the ContentView as follows (using @EnvironmentObject):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var person: Person

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
             Text(person.name)
            TextField("Name", text: $person.name)
        }

            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

... and assign the environment object on the scene delegate:

```
window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(Person()))
```

everything works as it should. But if instead, I change the variable Person to:

```
@ObservedObject var person: Person = Person()
```

I get this error on compile time:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)

[image]

I'm also using the latest version of macOS Catalina: 19A546d and XCode 11 Beta 7 (11M392r). Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try to make Person a subclass of NSObject. This was solving the problem for me.

Comment: @MarcT. Are `@Published`-setters calling objectWillChange correctly incase `ObservableObject` is a subclass of NSObject now? In beta6 and before it did not and you had to call objectWillChange manually inside willSet.

Comment: @Published is the new declaration that does this for you from beta 7, there is an alternative to do this manually (different to the one you used to have in beta 6 or earlier) but this shouldn’t be a problem as it works fine for iOS / iPadOS